# Computed observable dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I have an input field that should be populated dynamically when a selectbox changes it's value. So, I binded the variable to the input and another value to the selectbox's selected value. Now I want to be able to change the input value programmatically: for certains values of the selectbox the value should be an empty string and for others I should set it with some javascript code when the user does some actions. I though to use a computed function, so I can return the empty string but this lead me to a problem: how can I then set the value programmatically when the other selectbox options are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to default in a value into the `input` whenever the `select` changes and allow a user to update it freely, then a good choice is to use a [manual subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables).

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.selectedValue = ko.observable();
   this.otherValue = ko.observable();

   this.selectedValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       //perform whatever logic that you need to determine how the other value should be populated based on the dropdown's current value (newValue)
       this.otherValue(calculatedValue);
   }, this);
};
```

Comment: my real goal is to have an empty value for all the select box options except some that should prompt the user to enter a value manually and then set it. If the user select back an option that should have the empty string as input value knockout should set the string empty

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ELywY/ or do the options have actual values that go with them and some you can override?

Comment: using the subscriber I've solved my problem. Your solution works, thank you